# Shared Hosting Plans With Cpanel Duplicating Websites On Subdomains

Tags: seo, cpanel, shared-hosting, add-on-domain

I have a shared hosting plan at one of the biggest hosting company. I host there a 3 sites. Today I just discovered that every site is available under a subdomain of my main domain (that was required to add at the sign up).

So `samplewebsite.com` is available in two ways:

```
1. samplewebsite.com
2. samplewebsite.maindomainname.com
```

For me it's simple duplication and I think it is harmful for my sites. The support told me that it's a default behavior for shared hosting with Cpanel and the only way to avoid this is upgrading to a VPS. I tried to delete the subdomains manually, but couldn't do it without deleting the added domain so it's not possible to delete them only if I remove my sites from the hosting plan.

So what should I do now? Do you think Google wont index the subdomains until I don't link them, therefore it's not a problem? Or should I have find another hosting?

I think thousands of websites are duplicated this way just at this company and since it's a default behavior I'm not sure how it affects seo. How would you deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using cPanel's Addon domains? These indeed must point to a subdomain.

> it's a default behavior for shared hosting with Cpanel

Yes, it's default behaviour.

> Do you think Google wont index the subdomains until I don't link them, therefore it's not a problem?

If you never link to the subdomain then it's unlikely that Google will index it - but it is possible. (But even if Google did index it, whether it would rank higher than the Addon domain is another matter.)

> the only way to avoid this is upgrading to a VPS

No, it's not the only way. In fact, it's relatively trivial to 301 redirect the subdomain to the Addon domain using `.htaccess` on Apache (per-directory Apache config file). This will resolve any possibility of the subdomain being indexed. However, (shared) hosting support rarely deal with `.htaccess` issues/solutions.

In the `.htaccess` file in the root of the Addon domain (often a subdirectory of the main domain's document root, when the subdomain is configured as a subdirectory - but this isn't necessarily the case), try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where `example.com` is your main domain. Include/omit the `www` subdomain in the *substitution* as required.

Comment: Yes, I'm using cPanel's Addon domains. Thanks for the detailed explanation!